# Pyspark directStreams foreachRdd always has empty RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have been trying to read my data from a Kafka topic and writing it to a parquet file.  So far I have everything working, except the foreachRdd function.  I can see the data when I use the map on the dstream, but the next step of using the foreachRdd, the Rdd is always empty and I don't know why.

My environment is Ubuntu running both Kafka and Spark standalone.  I am using the pyspark shell.  I'm new to python, so there is a lot that I am still stumbling on with the syntax and am not sure if that is where my problem is.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a copy of my code that I have been pasting in the pyspark shell

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.sql.types import *             
import json

kafkaBroker = 'localhost:9092'
consumer_group = 'spark-streaming'
topic = 'test'
batchTimeDur=5

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, batchTimeDur)
directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": kafkaBroker})

#change string to json string
lines = directKafkaStream.map(lambda v: json.loads(v[1]))

# show what is in the stream
lines.map(lambda x: 'rec in this line: %s\n' % x).pprint()

# save lines to file
lines.foreachRDD(lambda x: saveAsParquet(x))

def saveAsParquet(rdd):
    print('in save a parquet')
    if not rdd.isEmpty:
        df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, buildSchema())
        #df.write.parquet('file:///vagrant/streamed-parquet', mode='overwrite')
        print('  writing file')
        df.write.parquet('file:///vagrant/streamed-parquet', mode='append')
    print('return save as parquet')
    return rdd

ssc.start()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RDD.isEmpty` is a method, not a property, therefore according to the [language defintion](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), `rdd.isEmpty` will be evaluated as true in a Boolean context:

> the following values are interpreted
>   as false: "False", "None", numeric zero of all types, and empty
>   strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists,
>   dictionaries, sets and frozensets).  All other values are interpreted
>   as true.

and subsequently `if not rdd.isEmpty` will be false.

You should:

```
if not rdd.isEmpty(): 
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  That fixed my problem.